# Sorting ipod playlists by ID

Tags: ios, objective-c, nssortdescriptor, mpmediaquery

Im trying to fetch all the user's playlists from iPod and sort them by playlist's ID.
This is what I did so far:

```
MPMediaQuery *allPlaylistsQuery = [MPMediaQuery playlistsQuery];
NSArray *allPlaylists = [allPlaylistsQuery collections];
NSArray *sortedPlaylists = [allPlaylists sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:MPMediaPlaylistPropertyPersistentID ascending:YES]]];
```

But I get exception:

```
'[<MPConcreteMediaPlaylist 0x14f38590> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key playlistPersistentID.'
```

So whats the easiest (and efficiet) why to do such sort?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for the exception is that `MPMediaItem` uses the method `valueForProperty:` to query property values, rather than `valueForKey:` which would make it KVC-compliant.  Why is doesn't support `valueForKey:` is a bit of a mystery to me as it would make the class much more useful, for example the code you supplied in your question would have worked I reckon.

Untested:

```
MPMediaQuery *allPlaylistsQuery = [MPMediaQuery playlistsQuery];
NSArray *allPlaylists = [allPlaylistsQuery collections];
NSArray *sorted = [allPlaylists sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(id obj1, id obj2) {
    NSNumber *id1 = [(MPMediaItem *)obj1 valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyPersistentID];
    NSNumber *id2 = [(MPMediaItem *)obj2 valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyPersistentID];
    return [id1 compare:id2];
}];
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, do you maybe know if its possible to fetch the playlist already sorted by id?

Comment: @Mario Sorry, I don't - I've never used that API.